# Set PK in Mysql database with autoincrement(string,int)

Tags: mysql

I want to have a composite primarykey with (string,int) format where the string is a default value and int is set to autoincrement. Is it possible to achieve this. I need it in the  below format

```
   TC_01
   TC_02
   TC_03
   .
   .
   .
```

so on

Comment: Why have such key? If your string value is constant, then just have it in separate column and do auto-incrementing on `int` column. But if your prefix is always same - you don't even(or more - you shouldn't) need to store it separately. Just add it in application or output.

Comment: Another one of those.. this makes **no sense at all**, please don't do this or if you really, really want to - just don't use MySQL and auto_increment for that. Auto_increment isn't used so you can show those numbers to people looking at your website, they are not designed to be sequential and you can't autoincrement strings. Like Alma Do said - just append TC_ when you're echoing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the auto incremented value is identified *just before* insertion into the table, you should better depend on a *before insert trigger* on your table.

To set the concatenated string as in the form `TC_002` etc, you need following steps in the trigger body.

Let us say if your `str_field` is defined as `default 'TC'`, then

```
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.str_field = concat( NEW.str_field, '_', NEW.auto_int_field );
END;
```

**Note**:

- In case you have input a specific value, that is used for
  concatenation.
- In case if `str_field` allows null and you have not defined a default
  value and you have not input any value for the same for insertion, the
  `concat( NEW.str_field, ...` results a `NULL`.

You can define composite `unique key` on `str_field` and `auto_int_field` primary key field.

```
Constraint UK_CMP unique key ( str_field, auto_int_field )
```

---

***EDIT***:

> when i use this trigger am getting str_field as TC_0 in all rows. But i should get TC_1,TC_2 etc.

You need an example like this:

```
mysql> drop table if exists cmp_pk;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

mysql> create table cmp_pk(
    ->   str varchar(10) not null unique default 'TC_',
    ->   id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ->   constraint uk_cmp unique key( str, id )
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.65 sec)

mysql>
mysql> drop trigger if exists bi_cmp_pk;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create trigger bi_cmp_pk before insert on cmp_pk
    -> for each row begin
    ->   SET @NEW_ID := ( SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    ->            WHERE TABLE_NAME='cmp_pk' AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() );
    ->   SET NEW.str = concat( NEW.str, @NEW_ID );
    -> end;
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql>
mysql> insert into cmp_pk values();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from cmp_pk;
+------+----+
| str  | id |
+------+----+
| TC_1 |  1 |
+------+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> insert into cmp_pk values();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from cmp_pk;
+------+----+
| str  | id |
+------+----+
| TC_1 |  1 |
| TC_2 |  2 |
+------+----+
```

Comment: when i use this trigger am getting str_field as TC_0 in all rows. But i should get TC_1,TC_2 etc

Comment: This trigger (code copy-paste) gives me the first row as expected and this error for the second insert: 'ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'str' cannot be null'. Other tests gave me understanding that AUTO_INCREMENT value is NULL while it is BEFORE INSERT.

Comment: @egvo: I just tested it again on **5.7.28-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)** environment. And the above process succeeded with no issues. Please let us know if you have altered any of the statements. post your used code blocks in the same sequence of their execution.

Comment: @ravinder-reddy Tested it again - it fails. I copy-pasted. My version is 8.0.22 MySQL Community Server - GPL. May it be versions differences?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  bi_cmp_pk
BEFORE INSERT ON cmp_pk
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET @NEW_ID := ( SELECT last_insert_id()+1 from cmp_pk limit 1 );
SET NEW.str = concat( NEW.str, @NEW_ID );
end;
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

this trigger should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually i dont know what actually you want but may this code will help you

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_name (
col1 varchar(255) DEFAULT 'TC_',
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (col1,id));
```

Comment: Am getting this error.Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key. And can i achieve it without using composite PK

Comment: Because, auto increment can only be used for single column primary key fields but not composite keys.

Comment: yes. But how do i concatenate these two columns and use